# How to make an object's property increase with a button click in net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, model-view-controller, nullreferenceexception

I would like to be able to change a books property (availability, +1 if I click "return" button or -1 if I click "loan" button").

I've been toying around and rewriting code for a while, but figured out I won't get it by myself since maybe I'm not fully aware of the theory behind net core

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Loan(string id)
{
    if (id == null || _context.Books == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var book = await _context.Books
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.BookCode == id);
    if (book == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    else if (book.Availability == 0)
    { 
        return BadRequest();
    }
    else 
    {
        book.Availability = (sbyte)(book.Availability - 1);
        return View("Index");
    }
}
```

I was hoping to see the books index again, but with one less available book, after clicking on "loan" button. Instead, I got this error

```
"System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'"
```

referring to the razor view for the index right on model (first line)

```
@foreach (var item in Model) 
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Author)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.YearPublished)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BookCode)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Availability)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: When you are using the `Model` in a view this mean your view is strongly typed. Therefore you need to pass the model data like `return View("Index", book);` in your case. But this is single item, not a collection. So it's not clear why you use a `foreach` in your code.

Comment: That foreach is the one generated when CRUD is implemented. In this case, i would like to get the full list like when showing the index, just that certain item (the one i referred to when clicking the button "loan") but with one less in availability. Example: 

I click "loan" on "the picture of dorian gray", which has "2" in availability, then i get the whole list but for that item the availability is "1"

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Replaced the Loan method with this one:

```
   public async Task<IActionResult> Loan(string id)
    {
        if (id == null || _context.Books == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var book = await _context.Books
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.BookCode == id);
        if (book == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else if (book.Availability == 0)
        {
            return View("Index", await _context.Books.ToListAsync());
        }
        else {

            book.Availability--;
            _context.Update(book);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return View("Index", await _context.Books.ToListAsync());

        }
```

Not really sure, but seems i needed to return an IEnumerable so index view could do its work, and also save update right after the increase or decrease